# I want to grep words that have a hyphen in the middle and start with uppercase letter + words that start with uppercase letter without hyphen

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want the regex that allows me to match words that have hyphen in the middle and start with uppercase letter + words that start with uppercase letter without hyphen.
also i want only the first letter to be uppercase, all the others are lowercase, something like (ENGLAND) is not what i need, because all letters are uppercase

I will give examples for all the wanted words' structure:

```
Wilkes-Barre
California
```

I have tried:

```
[A-Z][a-z-]\+[A-Z][a-z]\+
```

but it only matches things like Wilkes-Barre it doesnt match California
also tried

`[A-Z][a-z-]\+`

this one matches things like California, but it matches Wilkes-Barre as it is 2 words: Wilkes-    and Barre

So if someone please can help me find the regex that matches those 2 types of words, so if grep a file that has

```
Wilkes-Barre
California
ENGLAND
rome
```

It will only match the first 2 and it will give 2 matches not 3.

Comment: `ENGLAND` starts with an uppercase letter. Why should `California` match and not `ENGLAND`?

Comment: only the first letter is upper all the others are lowercase

Comment: Please do not answer in comment. Edit your question and add the missing information such that it is complete and non-ambiguous. Note: "_normal_" is not an accurate description. Lower case would be better.

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous. Do you want to match words, as you wrote, or lines? Do you have at most one hyphen or do you want `Foo-Bar-Baz` to also match? Shall a single upper-case letter match? And `A-Bar`, `A-B`, `Foo-A`? When you write _in the middle_, do really mean that the hyphen shall be the middle character or anywhere inside a word?

Comment: And also, shall a line like `-Foo` match?

Answer (score 2):

You do not specify if a single upper-case latter should match. Let's assume the answer is yes. The following should do what you want:

```sh
$ grep -E '^((^|-)[A-Z][a-z]*)+$' data.txt 
Wilkes-Barre
California
```

It matches entire lines (because of the leading `^` and trailing `$`) of one or more tokens (one or more because of the `+`) where each token is a hyphen or the beginning of the line (`(^|-)`) followed by a single upper case letter (`[A-Z]`) and zero or more lower case letters (`[a-z]*`).

If there must be at least one lower case letter after the upper case letter, just replace the `*` by a `+`:

```sh
grep -E '^((^|-)[A-Z][a-z]+)+$' data.txt
```

These regexes also match a line like `-Foobar`. If this is not wanted the following excludes lines that start with a hyphen:

```sh
grep -E '^[A-Z][a-z]*(-[A-Z][a-z]*)*$' data.txt
```

or (if at least one lower case letter is required):

```sh
grep -E '^[A-Z][a-z]+(-[A-Z][a-z]+)*$' data.txt
```

Finally, if there is at most one hyphen (no `Foo-Bar-Baz`):

```sh
grep -E '^[A-Z][a-z]*(-[A-Z][a-z]*)?$' data.txt
```

or:

```sh
grep -E '^[A-Z][a-z]+(-[A-Z][a-z]+)?$' data.txt
```

Comment: for some reason it doesnt work, could it be because of my system?

Comment: _it doesn't work_ is the worst possible problem description. What happens, exactly?

Comment: It also matches `-Rome`, where the hyphen is not in the middle.

Comment: @WalterA Absolutely. But as this is not explicitly excluded by the OP who seem to use _middle_ in a very broad sense, it might be what they want. Note that there are many other ambiguities in the question (`Foo-Bar-Baz`, `A`, `A-Foo`, `Foo-A`...)

Comment: A part of the title and repeated in the question is  `start with uppercase letter`. I agree that the rules about where the hyphen may occur is ambiguites, I do like your attempt to avoid using the regex twice.

Comment: @WalterA You're right, the title seems to exclude leading hyphens. I edited my answer to include this case, plus a way to limit the number of hyphens to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the answer should be:

```
grep "^[A-Z][a-z-]+" test.txt
```

However on my system, the plus-sign is not recognised, so I have to go for:

```
grep "^[A-Z][a-z-][a-z-]*" test.txt
```

Explanation:

```
^      : start of the line
[A-Z]  : all possible uppercase letters
[a-z-] : all possible lowercase letters or a hyphen
```

**Edit after comment**
This, however, only shows the first part of Wilkes-Barre. If you want both, you might try this:

```
egrep "^[A-Z][a-z-]+|^[A-Z][a-z-]+[A-Z][a-z-]+" test.txt
```

Comment: in case Wilkes-Barre this only shows first part which is Wilkes-

Comment: @suliman: that's the reason I'm using `grep`, not `grep -o`.

Comment: it gives the same answer in grep, only that it shows the reset of the word but not marked

Comment: I edited my answer, using an extended grep. This seems to work fine. Keep out: `\+` has been replaced by simple `+`.

Comment: This will fail on `NorthCanada`, that shouldn't match.

Comment: @WalterA: NorthCanada, does that even exist? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Canada)

Comment: @Dominique I don't care about Canada, it matches a string without hypen and 2 uppercase characters when it has a lowercase in between, like `AnotherExample` and `IntelliSense`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
grep -E '^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(-[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)?$'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/fjUK24):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Wilkes-Barre
California'
grep -E '^[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+(-[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)?$' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Wilkes-Barre
California
```

POSIX ERE pattern *details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:upper:]]` - an uppercase letter
- `[[:lower:]]+` - one or more lowercase letters
- `(-[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*)?` - an optional occurrence of an uppercase letter and then one or more lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: If you need to match strings with more than one hyphen, replace the last `?` with `*`.

Comment: @suliman Did it work for you? I tried to keep exactly to the examples, but I can help more if you need to adjust this for any other terms/strings.